# Can the expression $\log \left[-\frac{b}{k}\right]+2\log \left[\frac{b}{k}\right]-\log \left[-\frac{k}{b}\right])$ be simplified?

Tags: logarithms

Can the following expression be simplified?

\begin{equation}
\log \left[-\frac{b}{k}\right]+2\log \left[\frac{b}{k}\right]-\log \left[-\frac{k}{b}\right]
\end{equation}

given $b,k>0$.

Comment: log of a minus value?

Comment: @FrankMoses -  Yes, its a complex number - but the total expression never ends up complex, which led me to suspect that it could be further simplified....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ log (-b/k) + 2 log (b/k) - log (-k/b)$$
$$ log (-b/k) + log(b/k)^2 - log(-k/b) $$
$$ log [(-b/k)(b/k)^2]/(-k/b) $$
$$ log(b/k)^4 $$
$$ 4 log b - 4 log k $$

Hope you would have understood

Edit: I am not sure however is the question correct or not because as per log definition $$log _a b$$ in this b should not be negative however for third term you have made b negative